# Datalist input showing options from another Vue component

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm quite new with Vue, and webdev in general. Am creating a simple hiking pack list as a school project. Have a component 'PackItem' that consists of input fields for brand, model and weight. In the backend I have a database with some items that the user can pick from. When selecting a brand, the model input will show a list of models for that brand, and when a model is chosen the weight input gets filled automatically.

```
<template>
    <div class="inputRow">

        <h1> Brand: {{ this.brand }}</h1>
        <input
            type="text" 
            list="brands" 
            placeholder="Brand"
            v-model="this.brand"
        />
        <datalist id="brands">
            <option 
                v-for="(suggested_brand, index) in getProductBrands" 
                :key="index" 
                :value="suggested_brand"/>
        </datalist> 

        <input
            type="text" 
            list="models" 
            v-model="this.model"
        />
        <datalist id="models"> -->
            <option 
                v-for="(suggested_model, index) in brandModels" 
                :key="index" 
                :value="suggested_model"/>
         </datalist>

        <input 
            class="product-inputs"
            type="number" 
            name="Weight" 
            placeholder="Weight" 
            v-model="this.getProductWeight"
        @change="this.updateItemOnStore($event.target.value);"/> 
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the component. The datalists and input gets their values from computed properties, that talk to vuex.

```
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'PackItem',

    props: {
    },

    data() {
        return {
            model: '',
            brand: '',
            weight: 0,
        }
    },
     
    ...
    ...
    ...

    computed: {
        getProductBrands(){
            return this.$store.getters.productsBrandList 
        },

        getProductWeight(){
            let weight = this.$store.getters.productWeight(this.brand, this.model)
            return weight
        },

        brandModels(){
            if(this.brand === ''){
                return []
            }
            console.debug('Item %d getting models for %s', this.uuid, this.brand)
            let models = this.$store.getters.brandModels(this.brand)
            return models
        },
    },
}
```

This all works great for the first PackItem, but when i spawn a second PackItem from the parent, the models list for the new PackItem will be the same as the first PackItem, regardless of choosing a different brand.

[Image: One item spawned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGmFU.png)

[Image: Two items spawned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4czx.png)

If I change computed property brandModels() to a method, and save the returning array from the store in local data and print it, I can see that the model list looks like it should, but those values are not showing up in the list for the user?

[Image: Two items spawned with printouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1bWQ.png)

I can also see in the logs that I'm getting the correct models for the selected brand.

```
Item 0 getting models for Hyperlite Mountain Gear
index.js:209 Hyperlite Mountain Gear models: Windrider 3400,Junction 3400
index.js:221 Got weight 907g for product Hyperlite Mountain Gear Windrider 3400
index.js:64 Creating item 1 in category 0
index.js:199 Brands list: ZPacks,Hyperlite Mountain Gear,The OMM
index.js:225 Did not find weight for product   in database!
index.js:199 Brands list: ZPacks,Hyperlite Mountain Gear,The OMM
PackItem.vue:119 Item 1 getting models for ZPacks
index.js:209 ZPacks models: Arc Blast
index.js:225 Did not find weight for product ZPacks Windrider 3400 in database!
```

So seems to me like I'm fetching all the correct data, and as far as I can see it should be displayed in the browser, but for some reason is not. I have no idea what is going on here...

### EDIT:

As suggested by @yoduh I've fetched the whole products table into the component, and do computed values there instead of the supposedly broken computed values from getters in vuex. This has unfortunately not fixed it. Can still see in logs that brandModels() creates a correct list of models, but the datalist still shows the wrong ones.

```
computed: {
    getProductBrands(){
        let brands = []
        this.dbProducts.forEach(product => {
            //var json = JSON.parse(product);
            var brand = product.brand;
            if(!brands.includes(brand)){
                console.debug('Adding brand %s to brands list', brand)
                brands.push(brand)
            }
        } )
        console.log('Brands list: %s', brands)
        return brands
    },

    brandModels(){
        if(this.brand === '') {return }
        let models = []
        this.dbProducts.filter(
            product => product.brand === this.brand)
            .forEach(product => models.push(product.model)
            )
        console.debug('%s models: %s', this.brand, models)
        return models
    },

    getProductWeight(){
        if(this.brand === '' || this.model === ''){ return } 
        let product = this.dbProducts.find(
            product => (
                product.brand === this.brand && product.model == this.model
            ))
        if(product){
            let weight = product.weightGrams
            console.debug('Got weight %dg for product %s %s', weight, this.brand, this.model)
            return weight
        }

        console.debug('Did not find weight for product %s %s in database!', this.brand, this.model)
        return 0
    },

},
```

Comment: I believe Vuex getters aren't meant to be reactive.  There is a note in the documentation that passing in params will break getters caching (a bug, but sounds like it never got fixed before the Vue team moved from Vuex to Pinia).  try fetching all of the brand/model data from the store, bring it into your component, and make computed properties that directly filter that data instead of having a getter do it.

Comment: yoduh pointed out what could be happening. While that approach would work... an alternative could be to change the return shape of productWeight and brandModels to be objects keyed by the values. Then you can do a quick lookup by id and get the same data. If you're using lodash you could use the https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy function

Comment: @yoduh Okay I will give that a go. Would it be best practice to let that data live in every PackItem, or have the parent store it once and pass through props?

Comment: @yoduh Tried your suggestion but does not seem to work. Updated my post with the code of computed values.

Comment: Would you mind providing a github repo or sandbox that reproduces the issue so we can see exactly how all the moving parts are working together?  A [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-visvesvaraya-4o47om?file=/src/App.vue) with the rest of your code would be great.  For your fetched API data you can just add mock data to the store. Once you edit the sandbox it'll automatically fork and make a new link that you can paste here (or github is fine too)

Comment: @yoduh Sure, my github main has PrimeVue UI Components, so not perfectly in sync with my original post here, but the issue is exactly the same.. Could not figure out how to enable editing in codesandbox, but here it is [packplanner](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-pond-5ncrpr?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the actual issue was with the pair of elements `<InputText>` and `<datalist>` on every item having the same `id` and `list` values.  The value for `list` and `id` connect the two elements together, but once a second item is added, another pair of `<InputText>` and `<datalist>` with the same `id` and `list` values is created.  Because no two elements should ever share the same `id`, the connection between inputs and datalists becomes confused and broken.

The solution then is to bind unique values to the `id`/`list` attributes.  I used the `uuid` of each item since it's a unique number:

**PackItem.vue**

```html
<InputText
  type="text"
  :list="`models${uuid}`"
  placeholder="Model"
  class="p-inputtext"
  v-model="this.model"
/>
<datalist :id="`models${uuid}`">
  <option
    v-for="(suggested_model, index) in brandModels"
    :key="index"
    :value="suggested_model"
  />
</datalist>
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-silence-y51wdz?file=/src/components/pack_planner/PackItem.vue)

Comment: Dang, I would have never found that.. Thank you a million times over @yoduh for taking the time looking at this!!